Using SUMIFS with MAP/LAMBDA
I'm fairly new to MAP/LAMBDA formulas and I can't seem to figure this one out. I would like to keep it a MAP/LAMBDA formula as the size of the table can change and I don't want to have to copy down the formula when it does.
Here is what the data looks like:




Checkbox 1
Checkbox 2
Checkbox 3





Leader
Status1
Status2
Status3
Total


Tim Cook
1
10
6
FORMULA HERE


Steve Jobs
4
13
10




My goal is to add up the numbers if the checkbox is checked. Let's say I want Status 1 and Status 3 added, I would have Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 3 checked.
Here is my attempt at the formula:
=MAP($A3:$A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","",SUMIFS(B3:D3,$B$1:$D$1,true))))

What am I doing wrong here?
The intended outcome should be:




Checkbox 1 = TRUE
Checkbox 2 = FALSE
Checkbox 3 = TRUE





Leader
Status1
Status2
Status3
Total


Tim Cook
1
10
6
7


Steve Jobs
4
13
10
14



Here is a sample sheet (Question 1).


You may try:
=byrow(filter(B3:D,B1:D1),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,sum(Σ))))



This is pretty slick. I'm familiar with all of these except for byrow. First time seeing that. This is great. Thanks!

My only suggestion would be to make it 0 if no checkboxes are selected. Currently, it throws an error.

I spoke too soon. Just realized this places values to rows that don't have values in column A. My guess is because I have formulas adjacent to it that are map/lambda formulas? I fixed by changing it to =BYROW(FILTER(L4:S,L2:S2),LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","",SUM(x)))). Still trying to figure out how to make it 0 if no checkboxes selected, though.

@DanCue To answer your comment. Wrap the old formula with IFERROR like this=IFERROR(OldFormulaGoesHere,0)

Thanks for your reply but I had done that and it only gave me a 0 for the first value. I wanted it to apply 0 to the whole column.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

I can do that, but it looks like you already had something whipped up. All you do to see my error is uncheck all boxes in row 1.

Added a sample sheet to the original question. Look at question 1 on that sample sheet to see what I mean.

So you need 0 applied from row 3 to bottom row (row 1000) if zero filters applied?

0 needs to be applied to cells if there are values in column A and no checkboxes are checked.

Added a formula in Cell_F3 to test out

Perfect. That works. That's awesome. I see that indirect formula. I think that may help me with the other question I have. Learning more and more.
